# Problem with nvidia driver (NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:04:00): 6, PE007e )

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, nouveau

Sometimes my system (Ubuntu 14.04 64bit with the latests proprietary drivers from repositories) hangs, artefacts appear on the screen and systems doesn't respond on any commands from keyboard or mouse. I connected to my machine with ssh and run dmesg, output:

```
[100002.771845] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:04:00): 6, PE007e 00dc 00ffffff 00000000 00000000 00000000
[100002.773784] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:04:00): 6, PE007e
[100002.775644] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:04:00): 6, PE007e 00dc 00ffffff 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

How to fix this problem? I tried use nouveau, but in this case suspend doesn't work.